# YoutubePlayerView goes black when i scroll down inside recyclerView

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have a recyclerview that will show all videos from youtube. i'm using YoutubePlayerView  to display it. The problem is everytime i scrolls down half screen the current video screen goes black and will not load anymore. The videos will load just fine if i don't scroll half screen

Anybody know about this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The YoutubePlayerView has to be fully visible, otherwise the video gets stopped. Since you are putting it in a recyclerview part of the YoutubePlayerView is not fully visible when scrolling and gets stopped.

In the documentation it says: Also, it is not permitted to overlay the view with other views while a video is playing.
On the [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView). You are probably not overlaying the video, but you are obscuring certain parts of the video when scrolling.

Comment: No problem. If you did find my answer helpful, please mark it as the  [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)