# YouTubePlayerView is losing brightness

Tags: android, xamarin, android-youtube-api

I'm using `com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView` in an Activity with `Theme Dialog` and NoTitle. My problem is that `YoutubePlayerView` loses brightness in regular size view but it is working fine in full-screen mode. How can I fix this brightness issue?

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="99dp"
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/BackVideoBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/media_left_nav"
                android:background="@color/transparent" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VideoLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="1/2"
                    android:textColor="#555555" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/NextVideoBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/media_right_nav"
                android:background="@color/transparent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Dialog", NoHistory = true, ExcludeFromRecents = true)]
    public class YoutTubeActitivy : YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.YouTubePlayer);
```

IMAGES:

[Video not started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgT5t.png)

[Playing video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YyPP.png)

[SOLVED]
The issue was triggered by the use of Dialog. Changed to Theme.Transparent and it is working properly.

Comment: This might help you.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903786/youtubeplayerview-goes-black-when-i-scroll-down-inside-recyclerview

Comment: @JaswantSingh The video is playing normally, not stopping and not getting "dark". I've upload screenshots. When the video is playing it is getting some shadow and removing the original brightness.

Comment: @Wagner, Do you see my code? I don't find any shadow when fullscreen or not.

Answer (score 0):

I use  com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView at my side, but I find there is the same brightness when fullscreen or not. Here is the code about YouTuBePlayerView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

public class MainActivity : YouTubeBaseActivity, IYouTubePlayerOnInitializedListener
{
    private int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    public void OnInitializationFailure(IYouTubePlayerProvider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason)
    {
        if (errorReason.IsUserRecoverableError)
        {
            errorReason.GetErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            String errorMessage = String.Format(
                    GetString(Resource.String.ErrorMessage), errorReason.ToString());
            Toast.MakeText(this, errorMessage, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
    public void OnInitializationSuccess(IYouTubePlayerProvider p0, IYouTubePlayer yPlayer, bool p2)
    {

        yPlayer.LoadVideo(DevConstants.VIDEO_ID);
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = FindViewById<YouTubePlayerView>(Resource.Id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.Initialize(DevConstants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
}

 public static class DevConstants
{
    public static string DEVELOPER_KEY = "YOUR DEVELOPER KEY";
    public static string VIDEO_ID = "_OBlgSz8sSM";
}
```

[image]